# subprocess error on qpython (OSerror)

Tags: android, python, subprocess, qpython

I'm trying to send command through socket with subprocess (python 2.7 (qpython android)).
 here 's the code :

```
#reponse is my command
x = subprocess.Popen(reponse, 
         shell=True,
         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
         stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
         stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
y = str(x.stdout.read() + x.stderr.read())
```

But when i'm trying, i've got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "ser.py", line 72, in <module>     
stdin=subprocess.PIPE)   
File "/QPython/QPython2-core/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
line 679, in __init__   
File "/QPython/QPython2-core/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", 
line 1228, in _execute_child 
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So, can someone tell me what's wrong, and how to fixe this .. Thx in advance for help...

Answer (score 0):

I found that commands don't work if you specify `shell=True`.
I had the same error.

You should use the commands and its arguments as a list; i.e.:

```
your_cmd = ['examplecmd', '-a', 'foo', '-b', 'bar']
```